# Code composer 6 linker file not placing variables

Tags: msp430, ti-ccstudio, linker, flash-memories

I am developing firmware on MSP430F2619. I need to store configuration information having 5 sections of 200 bytes. In order to read and write them independently I am trying to allocate 5 sections of 512 bytes each.

SEC_CALIB_1         : origin = 0xF200, length = 0x0200
SEC_CALIB_2         : origin = 0xF400, length = 0x0200
SEC_CALIB_3         : origin = 0xF600, length = 0x0200
SEC_CALIB_4         : origin = 0xF800, length = 0x0200
SEC_CALIB_5         : origin = 0xFA00, length = 0x0200

section_calib_1 : {} > SEC_CALIB_1
Section_calib_2 : {} > SEC_CALIB_2
Section_calib_3 : {} > SEC_CALIB_3
Section_calib_4 : {} > SEC_CALIB_4
Section_calib_5 : {} > SEC_CALIB_5

Then I am trying to place information structure using DATA_SECTOIN pragma

```
#pragma DATA_SECTION(Calib_Slot_1,"section_calib_1")
const Cal_Slot2_t Calib_Slot_1 = { 0x0011 };

#pragma DATA_SECTION(Calib_Slot_3,"section_cal_3")
const Cal_Slot3_t Calib_Slot_3 = { 0x0012 };
```

But only variable Calib_Slot_1 is allocated memory but not Calib_Slot_3

Program compiles successfully but during debugging it dose not variable  Calib_Slot_3 in watch window. Plus it dose not appear in map file also.

Comment: You did actually ask a question, we can't help people that don't ask questions. Please read the rules. Looks like you could have found a complier error? This is probably a better question posed for a TI forum or tech support

Comment: Try turning off optimization

Comment: Thanks Swaries . It actually works once we turn off optimization to zero. But Still it should have work with volatile keyword in case optimization is ON.

Answer (score 1):

Turning off Optimization will solve this issue.

Comment: Can you explain this answer a little bit, please? I'm not questioning its correctness here, just that it would be nice to have some explanation of why this happens.